# Horizontal gradient background works but solid background doesn't?

Tags: opensuse, suse, wallpaper, persistence, appearance

When I select a solid background, blue for example, in the background settings, the blue background will appear on my desktop for two seconds and then will change to black and will stay black. In the little preview window it appears blue. I can continue selecting different colors but my desktop just stays black.

If I switch from solid background to horizontal gradient background and select any combination of colors including blue to blue, which has the same appearance as solid blue, everything works as expected. Image backgrounds work fine as well.

This is so strange. I am running openSUSE with GNOME desktop, can anyone explain to me what might be happening?

Comment: Yes - I use GNOME

Answer (score 1):

Background color selection on openSUSE Leap 42.2 using GNOME 3 looks like the following screenshot.

[image: openSUSE Leap 42.2 Background Color Selection]

It's hard to imagine that there might be any trouble using that interface. Are you seeing something more like the below screenshot? First select the top-left "color" image. Then choose "Solid Color."

[image: Linux Mint MATE 18 Background Color Selection]

That's a screenshot from Linux Mint 18 MATE, and MATE is a continuation of GNOME2.